# Filter leading to different results when typed manually and via defined as a variable

Tags: excel, dax

I'm trying to create a calculated column indicating if a team has a prize or not from the table below:
[image]

To do that I need to count within the group if there's a player whose "Prize" field is not empty. Here's the 1st attempt:

[image]

### Dax Formula:

*=
Var **Player_Same_Team** = filter(Table4,Table4[Team]=earlier(Table4[Team]))
Var **Has_Prize** = len(Table4[Prize])>0
Return
calculate(countrows(filter(Table4,len(Table4[Prize])>0)),**Player_Same_Team**)>0*

Looks like it's going what I intend it to do. However, when I swap the filter content to a pre-defined variable, it gave me results that don't make sense:

[image]

### Dax Formula:

*=
Var **Player_Same_Team** = filter(Table4,Table4[Team]=earlier(Table4[Team]))
Var **Has_Prize** = len(Table4[Prize])>0
Return
calculate(countrows(filter(Table4,**Has_Prize**)),**Player_Same_Team**)>0*

The typed content *len(Table4[Prize])>0* is the same as that in the variable, so what may be causing the difference? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you assign it to a variable, the value of the variable remains constant. Therefore the Len is evaluated to a value, that you are then passing as a filter.

The first example works because the `CALCULATE` accepts a table as a parameter, and `player_same_team` is evaluated to a table, by using the `FILTER` expression.

In order for what you are trying to do to work it would have to be something like this:

```
= Var Player_Same_Team = filter(Table4,Table4[Team]=earlier(Table4[Team])) 
  Var Has_Prize = filter(Table4,len(Table4[Prize])>0) 
  
  Return calculate(countrows(Has_Prize),Player_Same_Team)>0
```

You can also write the measure in a slightly different way:

```
= CALCULATE ( COUNT(Table4[Team]),
  ALLEXCEPT(Table4[Team]),
  LEN(Table4[Prize])>0) > 0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I tried the codes in the 1st block and it returns a column of all "True". The second block of codes work well but I need to know how to properly define a filtered table and then use it in the "Return" section